# Why serializer.is_valid() is always false in this scenario?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to Update this model in Django rest-api but I don't get any idea why the serializer is always not valid when I try to Update;

**models.py**

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(MyUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE, to_field='email')
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)
    blood_group = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)
    dept = models.ForeignKey(Department, on_delete=models.CASCADE, to_field='short_name', null=True, blank=True, default="CSE")
    program = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)
    student_id = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='Student/Profile/Profile_Photos/', null=True, blank=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    current_semester = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)
    level = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    term = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    sec = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)
    sub_sec = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)
    complete_cr = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
    sgpa = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
    cgpa = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True
```

**serializer.py**

```
class ProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
   
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = '__all__'
```

**views.py**

```
class ProfileUpdateView(generics.UpdateAPIView):
    model = Profile
    serializer_class = ProfileSerializer
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
    parser_classes = (MultiPartParser, FormParser)

    def post(self, request):
        token = request.headers.get("Authorization").split(" ")[-1]
        print(token)
        try:
            token_obj = get_object_or_404(Token,key = token)
            user = token_obj.user
            data =Profile.objects.get(user=user)
            serializer = ProfileSerializer(instance = data, data=request.data)
            if serializer.is_valid():
                serializer.save()
                return Response(serializer.data)
            else:
                return Response({"invalid"})
        except:
            return Response({'failed': _('bad request'),},status = status.HTTP_406_NOT_ACCEPTABLE)
```

**Try to Input data**

```
{
        "id": 76,
        "gender": "Male",
        "blood_group": "B+",
        "program": null,
        "student_id": null,
        "photo": <image>,
        "phone": null,
        "address": null,
        "current_semester": null,
        "level": null,
        "term": null,
        "sec": null,
        "sub_sec": null,
        "complete_cr": null,
        "sgpa": null,
        "cgpa": null,
        "user": "mdsoad@gmail.com"
    }
```

What is the problem?? or there is any easiest way to update for this model??

Comment: What is the posted data?

Comment: Please see [ask] and how to write a [mre].

Comment: {
        "id": 76,
        "gender": "Male",
        "blood_group": "A+",
        "program": null,
        "student_id": null,
        "photo": Image
        "phone": null,
        "address": null,
        "current_semester": null,
        "level": null,
        "term": null,
        "sec": null,
        "sub_sec": null,
        "complete_cr": null,
        "sgpa": null,
        "cgpa": null,
        "user": "test_user@mail.com"
    }

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat See Now

Comment: What response do you get if you replace `Response({"invalid"})` with `Response(serializer.errors)`?

Answer (score 0):

There are better implementation for this logic.
When you want to update some existing entity, it's better to use PATCH method for it, and do it on designated endpoint.

> PATCH: api/profiles/PROFILE_ID/

also, it's good practice to use [Viewsets](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/) for it.

try this solution for your case:

```
def post(self, request): 
    instance = get_object_or_404(Profile, user=request.user)
    serializer = self.get_serializer(instance, data=request.data)
    serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
    serializer.save()
    return Response(serializer.data, status.HTTP_200_OK)
```